# Glyph origin of 录. Is the original form 禄, 録, or 剥?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

[image]

Did 录 or 彔 look like some wooden object being carved? Was it originally a knife chipping something which became 録 as in recording events on a wooden object? It also seems to resemble a knife stripping and peeling away outer wooden layers like in 剥 (which btw does not sound anything like 录!).

However, I've seen sources like in http://qiyuan.chaziwang.com/etymology-3605.html say that it's a bag with water dripping below and ultimately became 禄, though I'm not even sure how does a dripping bag end up meaning as blessing. What is the story behind this character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the original form 禄, 録, or 剥?

None of these - and I'm afraid that the *chaziwang*'s description of glyph origins also doesn't look correct.

You have a minor interpretation issue in the question. The link actually says that 「彔」 is the original form of 「淥」 (*to strain liquids*), while it uses the character 「彔」 as a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters) for 「祿」, not that 「彔」 *becomes* 「祿」.

The phonetic loan for 「祿」 explanation is plausible, while 「彔」 being the original form of 「淥」 is not supported in a graphical sense; oracle bones or [Shāng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [bronzes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) did not have a component which is described as a *bag* that looked like the top of 「彔」.

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 彔] | [甲](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jiaguwen/Reference/Reference)598 [合集28800](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28800&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 彔] | 彔伯簋蓋 [集成4302](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4302&jgwfl=) |
| [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) 金 | [image: 彔] | □弔多父盤 總8.4786 |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 彔] | 28 曾侯乙墓簡 |
| 戰國・楚 簡 | [image: 彔] | 145反 包山竹簡 |
| 戰國・楚 [璽印](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia)) | [image: 彔] | 214 古璽彙編 |
|  | **Shape A** |  |
| 戰國・楚 簡 | [image: 彔] | 魯穆公問7 [郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips) |
| [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) | [image: 彔] | [彔部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=106) [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 彔] |  |
|  | **Shape B** |  |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) 銅鏡銘文 | [image: 录] | 吾作鏡 |
| 楷 | [image: 录] |  |

<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>

[image: Well-pulley with a container used for drawing water]

「彔」 originally depicted a *well-pulley with a container used for drawing water*. The small dots around the bottom of the character represent drops of water, equivalent to 「氵」. The word that 「彔」 originally represented is now written as 「轆轤」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): /***roːɡ raː**/). The meaning *to carve wood* for 「彔」 (**/*b·roːɡ/**) is a phonetic loan.

<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 彔]</kbd>

Later on, the well-pulley shape suffered egregious graphical corruption, eventually becoming the shape of 「彑」, while the drops of water turned into 「水・氺」.

---

**References:**

- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [中國哲學書電子化計劃](https://ctext.org/)

  - [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation. A bucket from a well makes a lot more sense than a bag.